# How to draw text over filled rectangle by XOR-ing its color with GDI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm not sure if I'm expressing it right with words. The best way is to show it with an image. I'm trying to fill a rectangle while inverting the text color in it. Just like an `edit` control does:

[image]

So here's a drawing code (called from `WM_PAINT`):

```
//Erase background
::FillRect(hDC, &rcClient, ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));

//Draw text
::DrawText(hDC, text, text.size(), &rc, 
    DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);

//Draw highlighted rect & invert text
HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = ::SelectObject(hDC, ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
::PatBlt(hDC, rcDrawFrame.left, rcDrawFrame.top, rcDrawFrame.Width(), rcDrawFrame.Height(), DSTINVERT);
::SelectObject(hDC, hOldBrush);
```

But for some reason the background rectangle comes out as black, and I know that `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` is blue on this system:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to make your won brush instead from the system color, like: `CBrush brush_selected(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));`

Comment: And if this does not work, try to make the brush I suggested member of the class, due to its lifetime.

Comment: I think that selected text part is rendered on top of text, not xor-ed.

Comment: An Edit control does not invert colors. It draws the selection background using the system `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` color, and draws the selected text using the system `COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT` color.  The user can customize those colors in the Control Panel.  Actually inverting colors can be difficult, as the text might not be easily viewable in the inverted color. There are algorithms available if you search around for tweaking inverted colors to make text more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a different strategy; [drawing the text twice with inverted clipped region](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/transparent-text).

Comment: Thanks. His example of setting the clipping region with `ExcludeClipRect` and then reversing it with `ExtSelectClipRgn(RGN_XOR)` and doing the drawing twice did the trick. I'm curious though, why is Google Chrome reporting that site as `The site ahead contains harmful programs` when I try to [download a code sample](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/introduction-uniscribe)?

Comment: Maybe they classify some of the downloads as "hacktools", who knows.